# Need to use Http in url to make a REST API

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rest

I am trying to use http url from jquery and make an http request. Below is my sample code. I am getting error

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Also I am not able to connect to the url if I change it to https.

Please let me know if you have any solution to the problem.

```
        <apex:page>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <head>

          <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

                  alert("Hello world, part 2!");
                  getContacts();


            });


            function getContacts () {

             jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "http://urllllll",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 Username : "user",
                 password : "pwd",
                 domain : "dom",
                 Project : "Salesforce",

                 success: function() { alert('GET completed'); }
        });
        }


          </script>
        </head>

        </apex:page>
```

Comment: Plesae let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: The solution is to make your endpoint secure...

Comment: How can I make the endpoint secure ?

Comment: Are you talking about https://rakeshistom.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/fields-on-session-settings-no-longer-editable.png disabling the session setting for HTTPS ?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - the endpoint is from external system which cannot be changed. Its product of some other company.

Comment: An update here - I have asked the other system to create an ssl certificate and put the certificate in the server so that making call to http is authenticated.

Comment: Along with certificate I am using CORS for getting access to connect to the other tool.

Answer (score 0):

After generating the SSL certificate I am able to bypass the error : This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.Additionally I am using CORS to get access to the other tool.

I will update more on this.